# compounding conditions in a statement in R

Tags: r, csv

My Data set contains 6 columns of which Ozone, Temp and Solar.R are a part. I need to find out the mean of Solar.R values based on condition $Ozone >31 and $Temp>90 I am executing the below code but it is returning NaN

```
data<-read.csv("hw1_data.csv",header=TRUE)
mean(na.omit(data[data$Ozone>31 && data$Temp>90,]$Solar.R))
```

Pls let me where I am going wrong

Comment: Post the first few lines of the .csv file, or something like it. Did you check your data for weirdness before you read it into R? Did you check in R to make sure that the data was read properly?

Comment: Yes all was OK, correct answer posted below. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one to many ampersands in there.

Try:

```
mean(na.omit(data[data$Ozone > 31 & data$Temp > 90, ]$Solar.R))
```

From the help page at `?"&&"`:

> `&` and `&&` indicate logical `AND` and `|` and `||` indicate logical `OR`. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

---

By the way, this pretty much sounds like the "airquality" dataset that is already available in R:

```
mean(na.omit(airquality[airquality$Ozone > 31 & 
                          airquality$Temp > 90, ]$Solar.R)) 
# [1] 212.8
```

---

Oh, and doesn't using the space-bar make code *much* easier on the eyes?

Comment: Thanks, that was quick and to the point. Agree to all comments by you I was just scribbling and immediately pasted the code. Will take care in future.

Comment: @Arin, No problem. Welcome to SO :-)